# How to display large amounts of points(rectangles) in real time ? (visual C#)

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a project which is digitalization of analog radar. I have a PCI card which acquires data that I use. I need to do a PPI indicator, like on the picture [radar PPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sIJ6.jpg)

But I have a problem: The data display is very slow. I'm currently displaying data point-by-point (if signal is detected it'll draw a small rectangle at the calculated position). The azimuth discrete is 0,1° so that's 3600 discretes of angles and the radius is 500 discretes, so that makes it 3600*500 = 1 800 000 points max. Which is a lot.

Here is the part of the code where display of data is done:

```
private void kreslenie()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferCH1.Length - 1; i++)
        {

           if (bufferCH0[i] > 4000) 
                {
                    if (azimutR >= 0 && azimutR <= Math.PI)
                    {
                        surX = (int)(sx + (i) * azimutX);
                        surY = (int)(sy - (i) * azimutY);

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        surX = (int)(sx - (i) * azimutX);
                        surY = (int)(sy - (i) * azimutY);

                    }

                    this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(p, surX, surY, 1, 1);

                }



        }
    }
```

Is there any other way to display such big amount of points in real-time (or near real-time)

Comment: It would be better to do this directly on the graphics card, using a Game Engine like Unity3D, Unreal, or even XNA/SharpDx which is made for managing large numbers of quadrangles/triangles.

Comment: 1) In loop, you on each iteration create graphics, it is very bad. You need create graphics before loop. 2) if perfomance steel not good try  draw you data on temporary bitmap and after all data will be painted, draw this bitmap to `Graphics`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try is using a PictureBox control, and dynamically generating a Bitmap to display. You can do this by maintaining an array of the raw pixel data and updating it when information you want to display changes. Use the Bitmap.LockBits method to get a pointer to the raw image data, and then use Marshal.Copy to update it with the array of image data you are maintaining.  Here is rough example that just randomly generates an image with points filled at a given location.

**Edited:** 
To draw shapes you could just create a second array of image data for the background. You can create a Bitmap the same size as the other image, and draw to it using GDI. Next, save the background image as a byte array. When you generate your whole image, you first set it to the background image, and then draw your points over the background.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PointDrawTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public struct BoundingArea 
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
            public int width;
            public int height;
        }

        public struct Point
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        int bytesPerPixel;
        byte[] backgroundImageRgbData;
        byte[] imageRgbData;
        private Bitmap displayImage;
        private BoundingArea area;
        private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadPoints();
        }

        private void LoadPoints()
        {
            this.points = new List<Point>();
            this.area = new BoundingArea();
            this.area.x = 0;
            this.area.y = 0;
            this.area.width = 1200;
            this.area.height = 800;

            displayImage = new Bitmap(this.area.width, this.area.height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            //There are three bytes per pixel in format PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
            bytesPerPixel = 3;

            //Rgb byte data for the image
            int rgbDataSize = this.area.width * this.area.height * bytesPerPixel;
            imageRgbData = new byte[rgbDataSize];

            GenerateRandomPoints();
            GenerateBackgroundImage();
            UpdateBitmap();
        }

        private void GenerateBackgroundImage()
        {
            Bitmap backgroundImage = new Bitmap(this.area.width, this.area.height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(backgroundImage);

            int gridSize = 40;
            int rowCount = this.area.height / gridSize;
            int columnCount = this.area.width / gridSize;

            //Set background color to white
            g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);

            int penWidth = 1;
            Pen linePen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Gray, penWidth);

            //Draw horizontal lines
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                float y = i * gridSize;
                g.DrawLine(linePen, this.area.x, y, this.area.x + this.area.width, y);
            }

            //Draw vertical lines
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                float x = i * gridSize;
                g.DrawLine(linePen, x, this.area.y, x, this.area.y + this.area.height);
            }

            //Get rgb data from drawn background image and save it to array
            var backgroundData = backgroundImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(this.area.x, this.area.y, this.area.width, this.area.height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                backgroundImage.PixelFormat);

            IntPtr ptrFirstPixel = backgroundData.Scan0;

            int rgbDataSize = this.area.width * this.area.height * bytesPerPixel;
            backgroundImageRgbData = new byte[rgbDataSize];
            Marshal.Copy(ptrFirstPixel, backgroundImageRgbData, 0, backgroundImageRgbData.Length);

            backgroundImage.UnlockBits(backgroundData);
        }

        private void GenerateRandomPoints()
        {
            int pointCount = 100000;
            var r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
            {
                int pointX = r.Next(this.area.x, this.area.x + this.area.width);
                int pointY = r.Next(this.area.y, this.area.y + this.area.height);

                points.Add(new Point() { x = pointX, y = pointY });
            }
        }

        private void UpdateBitmap()
        {
            var bmpData = this.displayImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(this.area.x, this.area.y, this.area.width, this.area.height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                this.displayImage.PixelFormat);

            IntPtr ptrFirstPixel = bmpData.Scan0;

            //Set image array to default background image
            for (int i = 0; i < imageRgbData.Length; i++)
            {
                imageRgbData[i] = backgroundImageRgbData[i];
            }

            Color pixelColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.points.Count; i++)
            {
                Point p = this.points[i];
                int bitmapRgbIndex = (p.y * this.area.width + p.x) * bytesPerPixel;

                //Apply color at a specific pixel
                imageRgbData[bitmapRgbIndex] = pixelColor.B;
                imageRgbData[bitmapRgbIndex + 1] = pixelColor.G;
                imageRgbData[bitmapRgbIndex + 2] = pixelColor.R;
            }

            //Copy your bitmap byte array to the image
            Marshal.Copy(imageRgbData, 0, ptrFirstPixel, imageRgbData.Length);

            this.displayImage.UnlockBits(bmpData);

            pbDisplay.Image = this.displayImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working, thank you! I have a small question...I want to draw few circles and lines here (they would form a grid ). How should I do that ?

Comment: You can just create another Bitmap of the same size as your display area and draw to it using GDI+. Then each time you update your image, apply the background image first, and then draw points on top of that.